# which is <c-e> key on keyboard for vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I had installed [sparkup](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup) plugin in vim.and they say press `<c-e>`.I had searched the google a lot and didn't find how to press this key ? please some tell me what do they mean . is it key combination ? a single key ? or something else ?

Comment: enter `:h key-notation` in your vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A key with the Ctrl key modifier is represented using the `<C-key>` notation. For example Ctrl-R is represented using `<C-R>`. A key with the Shift key modifier is represented using the `<S-key>` notation. For example Shift-F2 is represented using `<S-F2>`. A key with the Alt key modifier is represented using `<A-key>` or `<M-key>` notation. You can combine one or more key modifiers. For example, to represent Ctrl+Shift+F3 you can use `<C-S-F3>`. Super is represented `<D-key>` in MacVim and `<T-key>` in gtk2 gvim. In gvim it doesn't work with all the keys.

The Vim key notation for other special characters is listed below:

```
<BS>           Backspace
<Tab>          Tab
<CR>           Enter
<Enter>        Enter
<Return>       Enter
<Esc>          Escape
<Space>        Space
<Up>           Up arrow
<Down>         Down arrow
<Left>         Left arrow
<Right>        Right arrow
<F1> - <F12>   Function keys 1 to 12
#1, #2..#9,#0  Function keys F1 to F9, F10
<Insert>       Insert
<Del>          Delete
<Home>         Home
<End>          End
<PageUp>       Page-Up
<PageDown>     Page-Down
<bar>          the '|' character, which otherwise needs to be escaped '\|'
```

source: [http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-*Tutorial*(Part_2)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_2))

Answer (score 0):

`<c-e>` (More commonly described as `<C-e>`) is shorthand for "Control-e"